# I am trying to embed a program in my program, can I?

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I want to run a program (In this example, Notepad) in another program that I am writing. I want Notepad to be confined to a box inside my program that I can define, let's say 500 x 500. Then I can add my normal window components like text and buttons outside that. I tried something with Runtime#exec(); as shown below:

```
private Main() {
    setSize(1920, 1080);
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1080, 720));
    setResizable(true);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    try {
        Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = runTime.exec("notepad");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        process.destroy();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I can launch notepad perfectly, but I am not sure how to add the runtime to my program (like how you add a button for example) , if it's possible. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: **I am not sure how to add the runtime to my program** can you be specific ??

Comment: It'll be quite difficult indeed to impose constraints on another program and bend it to your will. Notepad has a mind of its own. It's not going to want to cooperate with your restrictions. It can be done, but might this be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? What are you really trying to do? There's probably a better way.

Comment: Even if you could pull this off, which would be difficult, you'd get flagged by every antivirus program in history for poking and prodding in the memory of other software.

Comment: There is no direct way for Java to control Notepad. Just build a simple text editor directly your Java app.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention notepad we are talking about Windows here and therefore Winodws designed OLE to achieve this very thing.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683898(v=vs.85).aspx